# How to FAST calculate 2 norm / spectral norm of a matrix.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, svd

I meant reduced 2 norm, the largest singular value.

My current approach is applying the SVD decomposition of A via *"?gesdd"* in MKL, and then taking the largest singular value.

I think there should be faster algorithm, since we only need the largest singular value.

By the way, my matrix is dense.

Comment: Even if your matrix is dense, you can still try to use methods used normally to compute the largest singular value (eigenvalue) of a sparse matrix such as those implemented in [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/).

Answer (score 1):

Try Arnoldi Iteration if you only need the largest singular value. Usually it converges very fast.

Search Arnoldi iteration in Wikipedia. It's not easy to write it here.